# Вывод пользовательского поля объекта PRODUCT

Tags: php, битрикс

Добавил пользовательское поле для объекта PRODUCT.
Поле появилось в форме редактирования элемента > Торговый каталог / Параметры / Расширенные параметры

Вопрос, как мне вывести значение этого поля посредством api ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$productId = 12;
if (\CModule::IncludeModule('catalog')) {
    $arProduct = \Bitrix\Catalog\ProductTable::getList([
        'select' => ['*', 'UF_*'],
        'filter' => ['ID' => $productId]
    ])->fetch();
    if (!empty($arProduct)) {
        print_r($arProduct);
    }
}
```

Если нужны только пользовательские поля

```
...
'select' => ['UF_*']
...
```

или

```
...
'select' => ['UF_MY_FIELD']
...
```